# CodeIgniter 3.1.7 unbuffered_row() returning NULL but row() works

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am attempting to output a CSV from a query result. `dbutil->csv_from_result()` should work, but it only returns the column headers. No data is included.

I tracked it down to `system/database/DB_utility.php` which uses `unbuffered_row()`.

Any calls to `unbuffered_row()` return `NULL`. If I change it to `row()`, I get a result. It makes no difference if I use `unbuffered_row('array')` or `unbuffered_row('object')`

**Why does `row()` work but `unbuffered_row()` does not?**

Is this a bug in CI or am I missing something?

Edit: `row('array')` doesn't seem to work either.

Edit: It seems that calling `$query->result()` spoils `dbutil->csv_from_result($query)`. You apparently cannot iterate through query results AND then save the results in a CSV file. This *was* possible in CI 2.

**Is there any way to show query results AND save the CSV without running the query twice?**

Comment: are you sure you're using `csv_from_result()` correctly, like correct delimiter, newline chars, etc...?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Yes, I'm sure. This is code that worked in CI 2, but not 3 apparently. I've updated my question with more info.

Comment: I've never used this method `csv_from_result()`, but it seems you need to use the query itself, not the `query->result`.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but if you want to first display the results on the screen, you need to use `->result()`. Then, if you want to use `csv_from_result()` it returns NULLs. I think the only way to do this might be to run the query twice. Sigh.

Comment: and if you do it the other way around? First Save and then Iterate?

Comment: great question... tried that and the CSV saves, but the screen displays no rows. So it seems it's only for whoever gets to it first.

Comment: need to look into core, also this might be commented somewhere in the CI-forums or on Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced similar problem and found this:

I have this query:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
print_r($query);
```

Then I get this and `unbuffered_row` works fine:

```
CI_DB_oci8_result Object
(
    [stmt_id] => Resource id #106
    [curs_id] => 
    [limit_used] => 
    [commit_mode] => 32
    [conn_id] => Resource id #91
    [result_id] => 1
    [result_array] => Array
        (
        )

    [result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [custom_result_object] => Array
        (
        )

    [current_row] => 0
    [num_rows] => 
    [row_data] => 
)
```

BUT if I call `$query->num_rows()` before I get a different `CI_DB_oci8_result` object and `unbuffered_row` didn't work returning null

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
echo $query->num_rows();
print_r($query);
```

Hope this help somebody.